# What UI Component to make multiple and separated box like this?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I just want to know what components to make this multiple and separated box like you can see here below, of course with each row can be tapped so that it can show something on next screen. thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a UITableView with multiple sections. You will have to configure your dataSource to specify the number of sections in `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` will also have to properly handle your data/UI structure.

As mentioned by rmaddy in the comments below, the tableview in your image has its style property set to UITableViewStyleGrouped.

Comment: You neglected to mention that it is a table view with a "grouped style".

Comment: And under iOS 7 it won't look like this. Similar, but not the same.